# Kerberos master server to slave server automation?

Tags: linux, authentication, cron, kerberos, automation

I've set up Kerberos in my workplace running on Centos 6 boxes, and successfully propagated the master server database to the slave and also set up a cron job to update it automatically every 5 minutes.

I was wondering if there was a way to automate the process of switching the Master to the Slave in case the Master unexpectedly goes down?.

The only information I can find is having to manually switch the CNAMEs of the two servers.

Answer (score 0):

It is preferable to have your database in the form of a multimaster OpenLDAP backend. This has the effect of making you KDCs multimaster.